# saving a django orm model with a foreign key

Tags: python, django, orm, django-models

I am trying to figure out the best way to save a model that I've got using the django orm. I have a model/table, `User`. Additionally, I have a model/table called `ContactInfo`, where we store a foreign key to the User table.

I understand that common django orm practice would be to put the foreign key for the ContactInfo model into the User model, but at this point, we do not want to add anything to the already monolithic user table, so we put the foreign key into the ContactInfo model.

I understand that I can store the User model in the ContactInfo model, call save on ContactInfo, and it should save the User model, but what if I have a one-to-many relationship with users and their contact info? I would rather not have multiple instances of the user table within (1-many) instances of the contact info model/object.

If I can clear anything up, please let me know. At the current moment, the best idea I have is to store an instance of the ContactInfo list as `user.contact_info`, and override the save method for user `user.save()` to check for contact_info, and if it exists insert the `user.id` into each model and save. Unfortunately I just feel like this is a bit messy, but being new-er to django and python, I'm not sure what my options are.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Doesn't Django offer a Many-to-Many type? It'll create the "middle" table for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. Django provides well support for 1-N relationship. If `ContactInfo` has a foreign key of `User`, by default, it's a 1-N mapping.

```
ContactInfo   --------->   User
             N          1
```

So, there is only one `User` record in your database, looks like this

```
Table    User               Table ContactInfo
---------------------------------------------
id     user_name              id     user_id
 1       someone               1           1
                               2           1
                               3           1
```

And you don't need to override `save` method. When you need to add a Contact,

```
contact = ContactInfo(user=target_user)
# other stuff
contact.save()
#or 
target_user.contactinfo_set.create(...)#contactinfo_set is the related name of target_user
#Django maintains the foreign key things.
```

If you use methods above to insert a new `ContactInfo` record, then you do not need to iterate your `contact_info` list to insert user.id into the database.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you're meaning a custom `User` model or the standard model that ships with Django. If the latter, then Django provides a standard way of storing additional information, called *user profiles*, associated with each user. See [this section in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) for details.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I know there is a User model, I had just changed the names to something simple for the purpose of the question. My actual model is not called User, I apologize for the confusion.